Type 3 compensator for forward/buck converter
I am trying to build a isolated forward converter with voltage mode feedback. For some reason, I am unable to achieve required crossover frequency. To simplify everything, I have change the circuit to a buck converter. To simulate it, I am using LTspice with FRA analysis and LT1247 as a controller.
I am using the part in voltage mode as described in an article from TI (for similar part):

Designed parameters:

Vin = 8 V
Vout = 3.3 V
Ioutmax = 1 A
fsw = 200 kHz
Lout = 100 µH
Cout = 100 µF

As I am using ceramic capacitors, I assume ESR of output cap to be zero. And therefore I need a Type 3 compensator.
As the filter has a peak at 1.6 kHz, I put a double zero at half - 800 Hz. Double pole at half of the switching frequency - 100 kHz. Crossover frequency to the 10% of the switching frequency - 10 kHz.
Then I use these equations to calculate all components:

The problem is that when I simulate the circuit, no matter what I set as the gain of the EA, I always get the crossover frequency similar to the frequency of the double zero.
For gain = 10, fz = 800 Hz, fco = 10 kHz, fp = 100 kHz:

For gain = 100, fz = 800 Hz, fco = 10 kHz, fp = 100 kHz:

For gain = 10, fz = 3000 Hz, fco = 10 kHz, fp = 100 kHz:

For gain = 100, fz = 3000 Hz, fco = 10 kHz, fp = 100 kHz:

The simulated circuit for gain = 10, fz = 800 Hz, fco = 10 kHz, fp = 100 kHz:

Link for download of the circuit: LTspice circuit
Can you please help me out where I made a mistake?
EDIT: I have changed the circuit to the one I have actually build. The results of the simulations are exactly the same.
I have calculated the gain of the power stage to be at low freq:
Apwr = Vin / Vramp = 8/0.9 = 19 dB.
I also verified the gain by setting the gain of error amplifier to 1 and appling low frequency sin source to the amplifier and measured the output:


The simulated gain = 2.22/0.2 = 20 dB
I used the gain and LC filter parameters to simulate the circuit in Simplis:

I had to lower the gain at crossover parameter a little bit to achieve desired frequency. The results:

Simplis circuit
Then I used the calculated parameters to the LTspice circuit. Output voltage of the LC filter:

The problem is that with the same parameters the circuit is not stable and not able to achive the stable output voltage.
I have measured the circuit in the lab, the output voltage is stable, but I measured the crossover frequency to be about 300 Hz.
So what am I doing wrong?
Thank you

Is a type III compensator necessary, or even workable, for the LT1578, which is a peak current mode controller? Current-mode controllers can usually be stabilized just fine with a type II compensator. I'm not certain the LT1578 would work properly with a type III compensator.

Your expressions for designing the type 3 compensator are very strange. You can either look at my free ready-made templates with plenty of design examples featuring types 1, 2 and 3 compensators (all automated) or have a look at my last book on loop control which gives all design equations in design examples.

As pointed out by Hearth, the LT1578 is a peak-current-mode switcher so a simple type 2 compensator is needed. Before compensating the converter, you need to extract its control-to-output transfer function. For that purpose, you have to plot \$\frac{V_{out}}{V_c}\$ first and choose a crossover frequency \$f_c\$. You then extract the magnitude and phase at \$f_c\$ and, from there, you determine the components values of the type 2 compensator.
You can either take a look at my last book on loop control, or run the below automated template in LTspice that I will soon upload on my page. The calculation procedure is automated and the dc sources in the bottom of the schematic, display the computed values:

If you probe the op-amp output, you have a typical type 2 response:

In this example, I had a 10-dB gain excess at 1 kHz so the macro determines the components values to produce a 10-dB attenuation at 1 kHz with the necessary phase boost for meeting the phase margin requirement. A type 3 compensator will also be uploaded.

Hi. Thank you for you comment. I have simulated the circuit in Simplis and added the results to the original post. I am getting different results in Simplis, LTSpice and on the actual hardware. So whats the correct version?

I don't understand, the LT1247 you refer about in the picture you pasted, is a current-mode-controlled integrated circuit (similar to a UC384x). In your SIMPLIS simulation, you imply voltage-mode control so the two are different approaches. The CM requires a type 2 compensator, the VM a type 3. What is it exactly that you want to compensate?

I am using the part in Voltage mode, as desribed in datasheet from TI (similar part), by producing sawtooth pulses to Isense input. I have added the screenshot from the datasheet to my original post. As it should be in voltage mode, I think I need a type 3 compensator, or am I wrong?

Yes, if you are using the part in voltage-mode control - this is for an experiment I believe? - then you need a type 3. I have uploaded a series of LTspice compensators here and you can run the type 3 on your circuit and extract the components values. You need the control-to-output transfer function first (see my seminar), then place 1 zero at $f_0$, one zero before, one pole at $\frac{F_{sw}}{2}$, the second will be placed by the macro.
